# ElasticSearch: Suggestion Completion Multi Search

Tags: search, elasticsearch, autocomplete, search-suggestion

I am using the suggestion api within ES with completion. My implementation works (code below) but I would like to search for multiple words within a query. In the example below if I query search "word" it finds "wordpress" and outputs "Found". What I am am trying to accomplish is querying with something like "word blog magazine" which are all tags and have an output of "Found". Any help would be appreciated!

Mapping:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/" -d'
    {
   "mappings": {
      "product": {
         "properties": {
            "description": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "tags": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "tag_suggest": {
               "type": "completion",
               "index_analyzer": "simple",
               "search_analyzer": "simple",
               "payloads": false
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Add document:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/product/1" -d'
    {
   "title": "Product1",
   "description": "Product1 Description",
   "tags": [
      "blog",
      "magazine",
      "responsive",
      "two columns",
      "wordpress"
   ],
   "tag_suggest": {
      "input": [
         "blog",
         "magazine",
         "responsive",
         "two columns",
         "wordpress"
      ],
      "output": "Found"
   }
}'
```

_suggest query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_suggest" -d'
    {
    "product_suggest":{
        "text":"word",
        "completion": {
            "field" : "tag_suggest"
        }
    }
}'
The results are as we would expect:
    {
    "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "product_suggest": [
      {
         "text": "word",
         "offset": 0,
         "length": 4,
         "options": [
            {
           "text": "Found",
           "score": 1
        },
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Are you willing to use an ngram solution instead of completion suggest?

Comment: I actually previously had edge gram implemented with fuzziness but my scores were all messed up and was advised to use the suggest api for faster queries with large amounts of data. What's your opinion between the two? A critical requirement for me is having the multiple searches separated by a space

Comment: That last part is easy with an ngram solution. Not sure about the scoring, though. And I'm not sure about doing an multiple-term completion suggest. I'll have to look into it. I assume you want an OR search, not AND, right?

Comment: Which part are you referring to? I'll give you an example to help explain my requirements. I have a user type with first, middle, last, dob fields. I'd like to do a search where a query could handle any order of any amount of fields. ex: last, first, dob, middle or first, dob or just dob and return the user. The front end will be one text block to enter information. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to switch to using [edge ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) (or full ngrams if you need them), I think it will solve your problem.

I wrote up a pretty detailed explanation of how to do this in this blog post:

https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch

But I'll give you a quick and dirty version here. The trick is to use ngrams together with the [`_all` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) and the [match AND operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

So with this mapping:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "ngram_filter": {
               "type": "edge_ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "ngram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "ngram_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "_all": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
         },
         "properties": {
            "word": {
               "type": "string",
               "include_in_all": true
            },
            "definition": {
               "type": "string",
               "include_in_all": true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and some documents:

```
PUT /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"word":"democracy", "definition":"government by the people; a form of government in which the supreme power is vested in the people and exercised directly by them or by their elected agents under a free electoral system."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"word":"republic", "definition":"a state in which the supreme power rests in the body of citizens entitled to vote and is exercised by representatives chosen directly or indirectly by them."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":3}}
{"word":"oligarchy", "definition":"a form of government in which all power is vested in a few persons or in a dominant class or clique; government by the few."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":4}}
{"word":"plutocracy", "definition":"the rule or power of wealth or of the wealthy."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":5}}
{"word":"theocracy", "definition":"a form of government in which God or a deity is recognized as the supreme civil ruler, the God's or deity's laws being interpreted by the ecclesiastical authorities."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":6}}
{"word":"monarchy", "definition":"a state or nation in which the supreme power is actually or nominally lodged in a monarch."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":7}}
{"word":"capitalism", "definition":"an economic system in which investment in and ownership of the means of production, distribution, and exchange of wealth is made and maintained chiefly by private individuals or corporations, especially as contrasted to cooperatively or state-owned means of wealth."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":8}}
{"word":"socialism", "definition":"a theory or system of social organization that advocates the vesting of the ownership and control of the means of production and distribution, of capital, land, etc., in the community as a whole."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":9}}
{"word":"communism", "definition":"a theory or system of social organization based on the holding of all property in common, actual ownership being ascribed to the community as a whole or to the state."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":10}}
{"word":"feudalism", "definition":"the feudal system, or its principles and practices."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":11}}
{"word":"monopoly", "definition":"exclusive control of a commodity or service in a particular market, or a control that makes possible the manipulation of prices."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":12}}
{"word":"oligopoly", "definition":"the market condition that exists when there are few sellers, as a result of which they can greatly influence price and other market factors."}
```

I can apply partial matching across both fields (would work with as many fields as you want) like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": {
               "query": "theo go",
               "operator": "and"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

which in this case, returns:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.7601639,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "5",
            "_score": 0.7601639,
            "_source": {
               "word": "theocracy",
               "definition": "a form of government in which God or a deity is recognized as the supreme civil ruler, the God's or deity's laws being interpreted by the ecclesiastical authorities."
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used here (there's more in the blog post):

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/e4093c25a8257499f54ced5a09f35b1eb48e4e3c

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually checked out your blog before and I think it is awesome! In your opinion for this situation why would you lean towards the n-gram route then using the suggest api? Also have you seen before when incorporating n-grams and fuzziness the scoring becomes out of wack?

Comment: I like ngrams because you don't need redundant data. In a large dataset that could become significant. Scoring is definitely an issue. My sense is that there is a way around that, but I don't know off-hand exactly how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, also why are you doing: "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer" "search_analyzer": "standard" instead of just "analyzer" : "ngram_analyzer"?

Comment: Because you don't want your search terms to be analyzed the same way document text is. You would end up with lots of irrelevant results that way, since all the ngrams of your search terms would match ngrams from many other documents as well, at least potentially. Take a look at the "index_analyzer versus search_analyzer" section in the blog post for a little more info. (Also, "index_analyzer" isn't used in 2.0; just "analyzer").

Comment: Ahhh ok! That makes sense because I was getting an error but I am using 2.1. Thanks for your help :)